# Unable to get position of selected tab on viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

How many tabs will be created it depends on web service. It means I cannot discover how many Tabs are going to be Created until web service is called.
The tabs contain the products which I want to show in grid view.

In my project I have ShopProductsPageFragments.java where tabs get created. Please have look below code :

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CatPosition = getArguments().getInt("CatPosition");
    StoreID = getArguments().getString("StoreID");
    System.out.println("getStoreID in ShopProductsPageFragments="+ StoreID);
    System.out.println("getCatPosition in ShopProductsPageFragments="+ CatPosition);

    try {
        ShopCategoryData = (GetProductCategoriesByStoreResponsePojo) getArguments().getSerializable("ShopCatNames");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assert ShopCategoryData != null;
    List<Datum> shopcatdata = ShopCategoryData.getData();
    for (int i = 0; i < shopcatdata.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("ShopCategoryData in ShopProductsPageFragments "+ shopcatdata.get(i).getCatName());
    }
    ShopProductsPageView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_product_page_fragment ,container ,false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)ShopProductsPageView.findViewById(R.id.product_viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)ShopProductsPageView.findViewById(R.id.product_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    return ShopProductsPageView;
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    List<Datum> shopcatdata = ShopCategoryData.getData();
    for (int i = 0; i < shopcatdata.size(); i++) {
        CommanShopProductFragment commanShopProductFragment = CommanShopProductFragment.newInstance(i);
        String CatName = shopcatdata.get(i).getCatName();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("StoreID",StoreID);
        bundle.putString("CatName",CatName);
        commanShopProductFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        System.out.println("ShopCategoryData in ShopProductsPageFragments "+ shopcatdata.get(i).getCatName());
        adapter.addFrag(commanShopProductFragment, shopcatdata.get(i).getCatName());
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(CatPosition);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        fragmentManager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

}
```

Here, you can see how tabs are created. I am using same fragment for showing data in Tabs as follows:

```
    public class CommanShopProductFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
private int position;
View CategoryTabFragmentView;
GetStoreProductsByCategoriesPresenterImpl presenter;
RestClient service;
GridView gridView;
List<Datum> shopProduct;
ProductByCategoryGridViewAdapter mAdapter;
public CommanShopProductFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
public static CommanShopProductFragment newInstance(int position) {
    CommanShopProductFragment f = new CommanShopProductFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String CatName = getArguments().getString("CatName");
    String StoreID = getArguments().getString("StoreID");
    assert CatName != null;
    System.out.println("CommanShopProductFragment >>>>>>>> CatName="+CatName);
    assert StoreID != null;
    System.out.println("CommanShopProductFragment >>>>>>>> StoreID="+StoreID);
    CategoryTabFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_category_tab_fragment ,container ,false);
    service = ((LilubiApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getNetworkService();
    presenter = new GetStoreProductsByCategoriesPresenterImpl(this, service);
    String page = "1", itemsPerPage = "10";
    try {
        presenter.GetStoreProductsByCategories(CatName, StoreID, page, itemsPerPage);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return CategoryTabFragmentView;
}
public void getStoreProductsByCategories(ProductByCategoriesResponsePojo productByCategoriesResponsePojo){
    System.out.println("CategoryTabFragment in  getMessage="+productByCategoriesResponsePojo.getMessage());
    System.out.println("CategoryTabFragment in  getStatus="+productByCategoriesResponsePojo.getStatus());
    // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
    shopProduct = productByCategoriesResponsePojo.getData();
    mAdapter = new ProductByCategoryGridViewAdapter(getActivity(),shopProduct);
    // Set custom adapter to gridview
    gridView = (GridView) CategoryTabFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.category_tab_view_grid_view);
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Now what I want is when user selects a tab then list of products should be displayed according to selected category from the tabs.
All product data also comes from web service. Let me know if I missed any thing to explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am editing my previous answer

Edit:
you can use `viewpager.getCurrentItem()` to get current position //include this in your activity with viewpager

Comment: Can you please share some example.. I tried the above code however nothing changed.

Comment: I have tried viewpager.getCurrentItem() also but not working, Actually i am using same fragment for multiple tabs to show the different data. and that fragment called the web service according to tab category.
but because view pager its give me two position at time for smooth scrolling. is there any other way to solve this..